# Blur and Focus not working together

Tags: jquery, focus, blur

I have a form using some Jquery script.
I want my input to be automatically on selected when focusing or clicking on it in order to overwrite existing value.
And I want that on blur, on some input that belonged to a row, the total is automatically calculated.
It works well but when enabling focus and click, my blur code do not work anymore!
Could you explain me why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").numeric();
$("input").first().focus();

    $("input").bind('focus', function(){
    $(this).select;
    });

    //totaux prev
    $(".classprev").blur(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $('input[name^="prev"]').each(function(){
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        });
        $('#idtotalprev').html(sum + '€');
    });
```

Comment: Could you please provide html?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. You're calling focus on an element (without more information, my initial reaction is that this is a bad plan; don't use JavaScript to simulate behaviour to trigger a function, just trigger a function!) but you didn't bind focus yet. Then you want to bind a function on blur, but it's not clear if you're expecting a manual or programmatic blur. I would trouble-shoot whether the blur is firing at all before worrying about anything else. Is it possible that it's an event propagation issue?

Comment: Also, `$(this).select;` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, abnd sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: My blur fonction works fine, It just automatically update the total amount of a column each time an input of the column is updated whick works fine. I want only to allow numeric value so I have used jquery numeric you can see at begining, but my because of the use of numeric libraby, I have lost the  auto selection of the input when focusing on an input, its now inserting new value instead of overwritte value, thats what I tried to fix with my focus fonction which seems to be wrong, I can feel its not clear but maybe you see more what I mean?